# regex, append a find with string

Tags: regex, excel

I am trying to add sheet names to cells in an excel formula that do not have sheet names.
For example a formula on curr_sheet :
'other_sheet'!$B$2 + A1
should become :
'other_sheet'!$B$2 + 'curr_sheet'!A1

```
public static Void addSheetNameToCells(String formula, String sheetName) {
    String noSheetNameBeforeCellRegex = 
            "('[A-Za-z0-9-_]+'!)?[$]?[A-Z]{1,3}[$]?[0-9]+";
    System.out.println("qwerty-"+formula.replaceAll
            (noSheetNameBeforeCellRegex, "'"+sheetNmame+"'!$0"));
}
```

The above code gives me :
**'curr_sheet'!**'other_sheet'!$B$2 + 'curr_sheet'!A1
I think the solution is in backtracking, I tried `(?<!('!))[$]?[A-Z]{1,3}[$]?[0-9]+` but it conflicts with the $ sign in **$**B$2 and gives me this :
'other_sheet'!$'curr_sheet'!B$2 + 'curr_sheet'!A1
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Is there a case when $B$2 has no sheet defined?

Comment: @AvinashRaj won't work if I were to change A1 to $A$1.

Comment: @alessandroasm it will always have a sheet defined

Answer (score 1):

Taking on from what @alessandroasm suggested, a small change in his solution seems works for all scenarios - `(?<!'!)((?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]+|\$[A-Z]{1,3}\$[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will match cells in the format A1 or $A$1 not preceeded by '

```
(?<!'!)([A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]+|\$[A-Z]{1,3}\$[0-9]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/yO8rW1/2

Comment: just what I needed. Foolish of me to not have thought of '|'.

Comment: phew.. came across a situation it doesn't work in-'Calculation IRDA Circular'!AC4      http://regex101.com/r/yO8rW1/3